# Search for string that doesn't start with a certain prefix using regex + index

Tags: regex, mongodb, indexing

We are trying to use the index when excluding records with a fields that starts with a certain prefix, when using the following, index is not being used:

```
{"field": {"$not": {"$regex": "^abcd"}}}
```

And it takes forever to get the result.

But when using:

```
{"field": {"$regex": "^abcd"}}
```

The index is used and we get the result instantly!

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If the string is only alpha-numeric, you can use inequalities and avoid the regex altogether:

```
{$or: [{"field": {"$lt": "abcd"}}, {"field": {"$gt": "abcd~"}}]}
```

Since `~` is greater than `z`, that query will return all values that don't start with that prefix, as long as `~` is not a valid character in the value you are examining.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2iUXnKhbihr)

Comment: Sadly, it is still not using the index for some reason

Comment: Run the query with `.explain(true)` to see which queries it considered, and how they performed.  What is the spec/key of the index you are trying to use?